# Problem with multivariable gradient ascent for optimization

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I'm working with a physical experimental system to track its evolution in real time using a camera. Specifically, I trigger the camera to retrieve images and track the `count` of each picture.

My current program calculates the mean count (brightness) of an acquired image, and of a batch of n images, img_round. The goal of my program is to adjust the physical parameters `focus` `second_dispersion` `third_dispersion` in order to yield the highest count. I'm currently testing on static data where the change of the parameters doesn't effect the `count`.

Currently my code utilizes gradient ascent to tweak the values of the parameters. I start with an 'initial_optimize' which chooses a random direction for each variable and continues with it for 2 `n_images` rounds. For the third and so on iterations I start the gradient descent which fails to work.

This is my console, as you can see the parameters don't follow the direction that had previously achieved more count. Additionally, I get an error of division by zero. How could I fix this situation?

```
Waiting for images ...
C:\Users\blehe\Desktop\Betatron\speed_test\manipulated_image_45.tiff 15868.030894444444
 first 0, 0, 0   
 second 1, -1, -1
-------------    
C:\Users\blehe\Desktop\Betatron\speed_test\manipulated_image_46.tiff 15909.208680555555
 first 1, -1, -1 
 second 2, -2, -2
-------------    
C:\Users\blehe\Desktop\Betatron\speed_test\manipulated_image_47.tiff 15941.136126388888
 first 2, -2, -2
delta count: 31.927445833332968
delta focus: 1
delta phase_2: -1
delta phase_3: -1
count_focus_dir: 31.927445833332968
count_second_dispersion_dir: 31.927445833332968
count_third_dispersion_dir: 10.642481944444322
 second -1, -5, -3
-------------
C:\Users\blehe\Desktop\Betatron\speed_test\manipulated_image_48.tiff 15963.883659722222
 first -1, -5, -3
delta count: 22.747533333333195
delta focus: -3
delta phase_2: -3
delta phase_3: -1
count_focus_dir: -22.747533333333195
count_second_dispersion_dir: 7.582511111111065
count_third_dispersion_dir: 4.549506666666639
 second 1, -6, -3
-------------
C:\Users\blehe\Desktop\Betatron\speed_test\manipulated_image_49.tiff 15977.498833333333
 first 1, -6, -3
c:\Users\blehe\Desktop\Betatron\playground.py:196: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in scalar divide
  self.count_focus_dir = (self.count_history[-1] - self.count_history[-2]) / (np.abs(self.focus_history[-1]) - np.abs(self.focus_history[-2]))
delta count: 13.615173611111459
delta focus: 2
delta phase_2: -1
delta phase_3: 0
count_focus_dir: inf
count_second_dispersion_dir: 13.615173611111459
count_third_dispersion_dir: 2.26919560185191
 second -20, -7, -3
-------------
C:\Users\blehe\Desktop\Betatron\speed_test\manipulated_image_50.tiff 15982.286560416667
 first -20, -7, -3
delta count: 4.787727083334175
delta focus: -21
delta phase_2: -1
delta phase_3: 0
count_focus_dir: 0.2519856359649566
count_second_dispersion_dir: 4.787727083334175
count_third_dispersion_dir: 0.7979545138890293
 second -20, -7, -3
-------------
C:\Users\blehe\Desktop\Betatron\speed_test\manipulated_image_51.tiff 15977.498833333333
 first -20, -7, -3
c:\Users\blehe\Desktop\Betatron\playground.py:197: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in scalar divide
  self.count_second_dispersion_dir = (self.count_history[-1] - self.count_history[-2]) / (np.abs(self.second_dispersion_history[-1]) - 
np.abs(self.second_dispersion_history[-2]))
delta count: -4.787727083334175
delta focus: -21
delta phase_2: 0
delta phase_3: 0
count_focus_dir: -0.2519856359649566
count_second_dispersion_dir: -inf
count_third_dispersion_dir: -0.7979545138890293
 second -20, 1000, -3
-------------
C:\Users\blehe\Desktop\Betatron\speed_test\manipulated_image_52.tiff 15963.883659722222
 first -20, 1000, -3
delta count: -13.615173611111459
delta focus: -21
delta phase_2: 1007
delta phase_3: 0
count_focus_dir: -0.71658808479534
count_second_dispersion_dir: -0.013711151672821208
count_third_dispersion_dir: -2.26919560185191
 second -20, 1000, -3
-------------
C:\Users\blehe\Desktop\Betatron\speed_test\manipulated_image_53.tiff 15941.136126388888
 first -20, 1000, -3
delta count: -22.747533333333195
delta focus: -21
delta phase_2: 1007
delta phase_3: 0
count_focus_dir: -1.1972385964912207
count_second_dispersion_dir: -0.022907888553205635
count_third_dispersion_dir: -3.7912555555555323
 second -20, 1000, -3
-------------
C:\Users\blehe\Desktop\Betatron\speed_test\manipulated_image_54.tiff 15909.208680555555
 first -20, 1000, -3
delta count: -31.927445833332968
delta focus: -21
delta phase_2: 1007
delta phase_3: 0
count_focus_dir: -1.680391885964893
count_second_dispersion_dir: -0.03215251342732424
count_third_dispersion_dir: -5.321240972222161
 second -20, 1000, -2
-------------
C:\Users\blehe\Desktop\Betatron\speed_test\manipulated_image_55.tiff 15868.030894444444
 first -20, 1000, -2
delta count: -41.177786111111345
delta focus: -21
delta phase_2: 1007
delta phase_3: 1
count_focus_dir: -2.1672519005848074
count_second_dispersion_dir: -0.04146806254895402
count_third_dispersion_dir: -8.235557222222269
 second -20, 1000, -1
-------------
```

The code:

```py
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from ftplib import FTP
import shutil
import random
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys 
import time 
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from watchdog.observers import Observer

MIRROR_FILE_PATH = r'mirror_command/mirror_change.txt'
DISPERSION_FILE_PATH = r'dazzler_command/dispersion.txt'

with open(MIRROR_FILE_PATH, 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()
mirror_values = list(map(int, content.split()))

with open(DISPERSION_FILE_PATH, 'r') as file:
    content = file.readlines()

dispersion_values = {
    0: int(content[0].split('=')[1].strip()),  # Use 0 as the key for 'order2'
    1: int(content[1].split('=')[1].strip())   # Use 1 as the key for 'order3'
}

class ImageHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, process_images_callback):
        super().__init__()
        self.process_images_callback = process_images_callback

    def on_created(self, event):
        if not event.is_directory:
            time.sleep(0.1)  # Add a short delay to ensure the file is fully written
            self.process_images_callback([event.src_path])
                      
class BetatronApplication(QtWidgets.QApplication):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BetatronApplication, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.mean_count_per_n_images  = 0
        self.count_grad = 0
        self.n_images = 1
        self.n_images_run_count = 0
        self.run_count = 0
        self.n_images_count_sum = 0  
        self.record_count_history = []
        self.count_history = []

        self.focus_learning_rate = 0.1
        self.second_dispersion_learning_rate = 0.1
        self.third_dispersion_learning_rate = 0.1

        self.img_path = r'C:\Users\blehe\Desktop\Betatron\speed_test'
        self.image_files = [os.path.join(self.img_path, filename) for filename in os.listdir(self.img_path) if filename.endswith('.tiff') and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(self.img_path, filename))]

        self.printed_message = False
        self.initialize_image_files()

        self.second_dispersion_grad_history = []
        self.focus_grad_history = []

        self.plot_widget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.plot_widget.setWindowTitle('count optimization')
        self.plot_widget.setLabel('left', 'count')
        self.plot_widget.setLabel('bottom', 'n_images iteration')
        self.plot_widget.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        self.plot_widget.show()

        self.iteration_data = []
        self.count_data = []
        self.plot_curve = self.plot_widget.plot(pen='r')

    # ------------ Deformable mirror ------------ #

        self.mirror_host = "192.168.200.3"
        self.mirror_user = "Utilisateur"
        self.mirror_password = "alls"    
        self.initial_focus_direction = random.choice([-1, 1])
        self.focus_direction = self.initial_focus_direction

        self.initial_focus = mirror_values[0]
        self.focus_history = []    
        self.focus_lower_bound = max(self.initial_focus - 20, -200)
        self.focus_upper_bound = min(self.initial_focus + 20, 200)

        self.tolerance = 1e-3
        
    # ------------ Dazzler ------------ #

        self.dazzler_host = "192.168.58.7"
        self.dazzler_user = ""
        self.dazzler_password = ""

        # 36100 initial 
        self.initial_second_dispersion = dispersion_values[0] 
        self.second_dispersion_history = []
        self.second_dispersion_lower_bound = self.initial_second_dispersion - 1000
        self.second_dispersion_upper_bound = self.initial_second_dispersion + 1000

        self.initial_third_dispersion = dispersion_values[1] 
        self.third_dispersion_history = []
        self.third_dispersion_lower_bound = self.initial_third_dispersion - 1000
        self.third_dispersion_upper_bound = self.initial_third_dispersion + 1000

        self.random_direction = []

        self.image_handler = ImageHandler(self.process_images)
        self.file_observer = Observer()
        self.file_observer.schedule(self.image_handler, path=self.img_path, recursive=False)
        self.file_observer.start()

        for _ in range(4):
            self.random_direction.append(random.choice([-1, 1]))

    def periodic_processing(self):
        time.sleep(0.3)  
        self.process_images(self.image_files)
            
    def initialize_image_files(self):
        if not self.printed_message:
            print("Waiting for images ...")
            self.printed_message = True

        new_files = [os.path.join(self.img_path, filename) for filename in os.listdir(self.img_path) if filename.endswith('.tiff') and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(self.img_path, filename))]

        if new_files:
            self.image_files = new_files

    def upload_files(self):
        mirror_ftp = FTP()
        dazzler_ftp = FTP()

        mirror_ftp.connect(host=self.mirror_host)
        mirror_ftp.login(user=self.mirror_user, passwd=self.mirror_password)

        dazzler_ftp.connect(host=self.dazzler_host)
        dazzler_ftp.login(user=self.dazzler_user, passwd=self.dazzler_password)
        
        mirror_files = os.listdir(MIRROR_FILE_PATH)
        dazzler_files = os.listdir(DISPERSION_FILE_PATH)

        for mirror_file_name in mirror_files:
            for dazzler_file_name in dazzler_files:
                focus_file_path = os.path.join(MIRROR_FILE_PATH, mirror_file_name)
                dispersion_file_path = os.path.join(DISPERSION_FILE_PATH, dazzler_file_name)
                
                if os.path.isfile(focus_file_path) and os.path.isfile(dispersion_file_path):
                    copy_mirror_img_path = os.path.join(MIRROR_FILE_PATH, f'copy_{mirror_file_name}')
                    copy_dazzler_img_path = os.path.join(DISPERSION_FILE_PATH, f'copy_{dazzler_file_name}')
                    shutil.copy(focus_file_path, copy_mirror_img_path)
                    shutil.copy(dispersion_file_path, copy_dazzler_img_path)

                    with open(copy_mirror_img_path, 'rb') as local_file:
                        mirror_ftp.storbinary(f'STOR {mirror_file_name}', local_file)

                    with open(copy_dazzler_img_path, 'rb') as local_file:
                        dazzler_ftp.storbinary(f'STOR {dazzler_file_name}', local_file)
                        
                    os.remove(copy_mirror_img_path)
                    os.remove(copy_dazzler_img_path)                    
                    print(f"Uploaded to mirror FTP: {mirror_file_name}, {dazzler_file_name}")

    def calc_xray_count(self, image_path):
        original_image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
        median_filtered_image = cv2.medianBlur(original_image, 5)
        img_mean_count = median_filtered_image.mean()

        return img_mean_count

    def initial_optimize(self):

        self.new_focus = self.focus_history[-1] + self.random_direction[0]
        self.new_second_dispersion = self.second_dispersion_history[-1] + self.random_direction[1]
        self.new_third_dispersion = self.third_dispersion_history[-1] + self.random_direction[2]


        self.new_focus = round(np.clip(self.new_focus, self.focus_lower_bound, self.focus_upper_bound))
        self.new_second_dispersion = round(np.clip(self.new_second_dispersion, self.second_dispersion_lower_bound, self.second_dispersion_upper_bound))
        self.new_third_dispersion = round(np.clip(self.new_third_dispersion, self.third_dispersion_lower_bound, self.third_dispersion_upper_bound))

        self.focus_history.append(self.new_focus)
        self.second_dispersion_history.append(self.new_second_dispersion)
        self.third_dispersion_history.append(self.new_third_dispersion)

        mirror_values[0] = (self.focus_history[-1])
        dispersion_values[0] = (self.second_dispersion_history[-1])
        dispersion_values[1] = (self.third_dispersion_history[-1])

    def optimize_count(self):
        self.count_diff = (self.count_history[-1] - self.count_history[-2])
        self.count_focus_dir = (self.count_history[-1] - self.count_history[-2]) / (np.abs(self.focus_history[-1]) - np.abs(self.focus_history[-2]))
        self.count_second_dispersion_dir = (self.count_history[-1] - self.count_history[-2]) / (np.abs(self.second_dispersion_history[-1]) - np.abs(self.second_dispersion_history[-2]))
        self.count_third_dispersion_dir = (self.count_history[-1] - self.count_history[-2]) / np.abs((self.third_dispersion_history[-1]) - np.abs(self.third_dispersion_history[-2]))  
        self.count_grad = np.array([self.count_focus_dir, self.count_second_dispersion_dir, self.count_third_dispersion_dir])  # vector with partial derivatives 

        print(f"delta count: {self.count_history[-1] - self.count_history[-2]}")
        print(f"delta focus: {self.focus_history[-1] - self.focus_history[-2]}")
        print(f"delta phase_2: {self.second_dispersion_history[-1] - self.second_dispersion_history[-2]}")
        print(f"delta phase_3: {self.third_dispersion_history[-1] - self.third_dispersion_history[-2]}")
        print(f"count_focus_dir: {self.count_focus_dir}")
        print(f"count_second_dispersion_dir: {self.count_second_dispersion_dir}")
        print(f"count_third_dispersion_dir: {self.count_third_dispersion_dir}")

        if np.max(np.abs(self.count_grad)) <= self.tolerance:
            print("convergence achieved")

        if not (self.focus_history[-1] == self.focus_lower_bound) and not (self.focus_history[-1] == self.focus_upper_bound):
            self.new_focus = self.focus_history[-1] - self.focus_learning_rate * self.count_focus_dir 
            self.new_focus = round(np.clip(self.new_focus, self.focus_lower_bound, self.focus_upper_bound))
            self.focus_history.append(self.new_focus)                 
            mirror_values[0] = self.focus_history[-1]

        if not (self.second_dispersion_history[-1] == self.second_dispersion_lower_bound) and not (self.second_dispersion_history[-1] == self.second_dispersion_upper_bound):
            self.new_second_dispersion = self.second_dispersion_history[-1] - self.second_dispersion_learning_rate * self.count_second_dispersion_dir 
            self.new_second_dispersion = round(np.clip(self.new_second_dispersion, self.second_dispersion_lower_bound, self.second_dispersion_upper_bound))
            self.second_dispersion_history.append(self.new_second_dispersion)
            dispersion_values[0] = self.second_dispersion_history[-1]

        if not (self.third_dispersion_history[-1] == self.third_dispersion_lower_bound) and not (self.third_dispersion_history[-1] == self.third_dispersion_upper_bound):
            self.new_third_dispersion = self.third_dispersion_history[-1] -self.third_dispersion_learning_rate * self.count_third_dispersion_dir 
            self.new_third_dispersion = round(np.clip(self.new_third_dispersion, self.third_dispersion_lower_bound, self.third_dispersion_upper_bound))
            self.third_dispersion_history.append(self.new_third_dispersion)            
            dispersion_values[1] = self.third_dispersion_history[-1]

        self.new_focus = round(np.clip(self.focus_history[-1], self.focus_lower_bound, self.focus_upper_bound))
        self.new_second_dispersion = round(np.clip(self.second_dispersion_history[-1], self.second_dispersion_lower_bound, self.second_dispersion_upper_bound))
        self.new_third_dispersion = round(np.clip(self.third_dispersion_history[-1], self.third_dispersion_lower_bound, self.third_dispersion_upper_bound))

    def process_images(self, new_images):
        self.initialize_image_files() 
        new_images.sort(key=os.path.getctime)

        for image_path in new_images:
            img_mean_count = self.calc_xray_count(image_path)
            self.n_images_count_sum += np.sum(img_mean_count)

            self.run_count += 1

            if self.run_count % self.n_images == 0:
                self.mean_count_per_n_images = np.mean(img_mean_count)
                self.count_history.append(self.mean_count_per_n_images)
                print(f"{image_path} {self.count_history[-1]}")
                self.n_images_run_count += 1

                if self.n_images_run_count == 1:
                    self.focus_history.append(self.initial_focus)                       
                    self.second_dispersion_history.append(self.initial_second_dispersion)
                    self.third_dispersion_history.append(self.initial_third_dispersion)                    
                    print(f" first {self.focus_history[-1]}, {self.second_dispersion_history[-1]}, {self.third_dispersion_history[-1]}")
                    self.initial_optimize()

                elif self.n_images_run_count == 2:
                    print(f" first {self.focus_history[-1]}, {self.second_dispersion_history[-1]}, {self.third_dispersion_history[-1]}")
                    self.initial_optimize()     

                elif self.n_images_run_count > 2: 
                    print(f" first {self.focus_history[-1]}, {self.second_dispersion_history[-1]}, {self.third_dispersion_history[-1]}")
                    self.optimize_count()

                print(f" second {self.focus_history[-1]}, {self.second_dispersion_history[-1]}, {self.third_dispersion_history[-1]}")
                QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()

                with open(MIRROR_FILE_PATH, 'w') as file:
                    file.write(' '.join(map(str, mirror_values)))

                with open(DISPERSION_FILE_PATH, 'w') as file:
                    file.write(f'order2 = {dispersion_values[0]}\n')
                    file.write(f'order3 = {dispersion_values[1]}\n')

                # self.upload_files()

                self.iteration_data.append(self.n_images_run_count)
                self.count_data.append(self.mean_count_per_n_images)
                self.plot_curve.setData(self.iteration_data, self.count_data)
                self.n_images_count_sum = 0
                self.mean_count_per_n_images  = 0
                img_mean_count = 0  
                print('-------------')

            # if self.run_count == len(self.image_files):
            # self.image_files = []            
                # self.run_count = 0
                # self.n_images_run_count = 0
                # self.printed_message = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = BetatronApplication([])
    win = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```